# Why does bash not distinguish case in file names?

Tags: bash, macos, shell

On macOS 10.12.5, bash 3.2.57 is generally case sensitive. This is not the case, however, with file names. For instance:

```
mbp:~ $ rmdir a
rmdir: a: No such file or directory

mbp:~ $ rmdir A
rmdir: A: No such file or directory
```

This was done to verify that neither `a` nor `A` exists.

```
mbp:~ $ mkdir a
mbp:~ $ mkdir A
mkdir: A: File exists

mbp:~ $ rmdir a A
rmdir: A: No such file or directory
```

What is the reason for such behavior?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22297/is-bash-in-osx-case-insensitive

Comment: Not just bash -- **every** program interacting with that filesystem.

Comment: Case-sensitivity is a filesystem feature, not the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, as pointed out in the link given in the comments (thank you, Digital Chris), is that case insensitivity is not a feature of bash, but of the file system configuration (HFS+, not Case Sensitive).